# how to style in a loop React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, syntax, jsx

Today I'm working on a slideshow function. I just made a loop and I would like to style an element in the loop, but that went wrong.

slideshow.js:

```
import React from 'react';

let slideIndex = [1, 1];
let slideId = ["slide"];
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
} 

function showSlides(n, no) {
    let i;
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
    if (n > x.length) {
        slideIndex[no] = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex[no] = x.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";
}

const SlideShow = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={'slide'} style={{
            display: 'none',
            textAlign: 'center'
        }}>
           <img src={props.logo} className={'logo-banner'} style={{
                verticalAlign: 'center'
            }}/>
            <a className={"prev-photo"} onClick={plusSlides(-1, 1)}>&#10094;</a>
            <a className={"next-photo"} onClick={plusSlides(1, 1)}>&#10095;</a>
        </div>
    )
};

export default SlideShow;
```

My problem occured by line 22 and 24. because I gave it a style.display, but that doesn't work... has someone else a better solution. Please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid manipulating the DOM directly like this when using React. Doing so can interfere with React's [Virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html) resulting in unexpected behaviour.

Instead, you could store the current slide in [component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) and control which slide is displayed that way.

Here's an example. You could control the slides in a higher order component instead and pass them through as props if you'd prefer.

```
class SlideShow extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            slides: ['slide-img01.png', 'slide-img02.png'],
            currentSlideIndex: 0
        };
    }

    handleNext () {
        this.setState({
            currentSlideIndex: this.state.currentSlideIndex + 1
        });
    }

    handlePrev () {
        this.setState({
            currentSlideIndex: this.state.currentSlideIndex - 1
        });
    }

    render () {
        const { slides, currentSlideIndex } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className={'slide'}>
                {slides.map((slide, index) =>
                    <img
                        key={index}
                        src={slide} className={'logo-banner'} 
                        style={index === currentSlideIndex
                            ? { verticalAlign: 'center' }
                            : { verticalAlign: 'center', display: 'none' }} />
                )}

                <a className={"prev-photo"} onClick={handlePrev.bind(this)}>&#10094;</a>
                <a className={"next-photo"} onClick={handleNext.bind(this)}>&#10095;</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, the reason for the `map()` is so you can add transitions between slides if you want to. Otherwise you could avoid rendering the non-current images all together.